# Laravel say that Auth guard [] is not defined

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, routes, laravel-5.1

I'm beginer and I start learn and code with laravel...
To enable user login nad registration I write this *(as I see on one tutorilal)*:

at routes.php

```
 Route::controllers([
     'auth'=>'Auth\AuthController',
     'password'=>'Auth\PasswordController', ]);
```

and now when I type: http://localhost:8888/auth/login I get error:

> InvalidArgumentException in AuthManager.php line 71:
>   Auth guard [] is
>   not defined.

[image]

Also in view folder there is no auth directory and login.blade.php files and other.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your routes, but Laravel 5.1 doesn't include the auth files anymore. You can, however, get them from: https://github.com/bestmomo/scafold

Comment: @craig_h The files authentication controller files are [included](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/master/app/Http/Controllers/Auth) with Laravel, only the welcome controller was removed.

Comment: @MonkeyBusiness Have you made any changes to the `AuthManager`? Because [on line 71](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Auth/AuthManager.php#L71) of that file there's a PHPDoc block which would not throw an exception.

Comment: @Bogdan Ah yes, I meant the auth `view` files are not included anymore, not the controllers, which was a direct response to 'Also in view folder there is no auth directory'. Important clarification though.

Comment: Maybe is the version probem, becouse I use laravel 5.2.* not 5.1 ... How I can update my code with 5.1 laravel version ?

Comment: THE PROBLEM WAS A LARAVEL VERSION, becouse 5.2 is not stable - just alpha version

Comment: @MonkeyBusiness in the future make sure you **tag** your questions correctly. Because you're question has the [tag:laravel-5.1] tag.

Comment: Can you paste your authmanager file code here? and your authenticate.php should be injected with guardsas per the laravel 5.1  which should look  like  public function __construct(Guard $auth)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Make sure that your config/auth.php is updated if you've upgraded from 5.1.x to 5.2.

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v5.2.0/config/auth.php

Answer (score 17):

In case you edited your `config/auth.php`, e.g. to add another guard and your config is cached, your guards may not be reloaded. If you experience this problem, clearing the config will fix it.

`$php artisan config:clear` or `$php artisan config:cache`

I'm using laravel 5.5

Comment: I spent hours on this error, thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

This could be a problem in your config/auth.php file, where the 'defaults' array is setting a non-existing guard on Laravel 5.2.

Comment: This should be a comment

Answer (score 5):

The main cause of this problem is your system can not detect newly created guard.
Just run

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

If you are unable to run above artisan command or project in share hosting then write the below code to your web.php file

```
Route::get('/clear', function() {

    Artisan::call('cache:clear');
    Artisan::call('config:clear');
    Artisan::call('config:cache');
    Artisan::call('view:clear');
    Artisan::call('route:clear');

    return "Cleared!";

});
```

Now, write "clear" after your base url and hit enter.Hope your problem will solve.

Comment: nice approach :)

Answer (score 0):

**program directory App/config/Auth.php**

```
<?php
 return [
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Defaults
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
| reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
| as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
|
*/
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Guards
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
| Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
| here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
|
| All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
| users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
| mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
|
| Supported: "session", "token"
|
*/
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

   // define your Auth here..

   'your_auth_name' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'your table name',
    ],

],
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| User Providers
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
| users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
| mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
|
| If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
| sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
| be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
|
| Supported: "database", "eloquent"
|
*/
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],

    // add provider to your auth
       'table name' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
   // **'model' => App\User::class,**
  // here App\User is model so you have to generate own model using **php artisan make:model Model_name**


],
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Resetting Passwords
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may set the options for resetting passwords including the view
| that is your password reset e-mail. You may also set the name of the
| table that maintains all of the reset tokens for your application.
|
| You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
| than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
| separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
|
| The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
| considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
| they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
|
*/
'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'email' => 'auth.emails.password',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
], ];
```

Comment: please add some description

Comment: I have already define description in code as comment  with sample of code. and still if you have confusion please ask.

Answer (score 0):

Clear your config and cache

Php artisan config:clear

php artisan config:cache

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).