# Auth guard [vendor] is not defined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, reference, ide

i used of laravel 5.5
and my login page http://127.0.0.1:8000/vendor/login  have a error

```
InvalidArgumentException
Auth guard [vendor] is not defined.
```

my error

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect('/');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

my AuthServiceProvider code:

```
  class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
    {
    protected $policies = [
        product::class =>productPolicy::class,
    ];

    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();
        Passport::routes();
        Passport::tokensExpireIn(now()->addDay(2));
    }
}
```

please help me

my VendorLoginController.php

https://github.com/Tohidda/file/blob/master/VendorLoginController.php

and my auth.php

https://github.com/Tohidda/file/blob/master/auth.php

and my web.php

https://github.com/Tohidda/file/blob/master/web.php

Comment: Please try to reformulate your question. Also, check out [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) why it's not good to ask your question as *"please help me"*

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34116211/laravel-say-that-auth-guard-is-not-defined?rq=1

Comment: update question thank you

Comment: @Kisaragi  not work for me

Comment: Please share your route file, also did you clear your cache? may be your config is cached.

Comment: @OsamaAlvi added...i clear cached but not work

Comment: Is the constructor in your controller setup right? would changing `$this->middleware('guest:vendor');` fix it?

Comment: @Das no?i change to $this->middleware('guest');  work but not reffer for vendor user